# Disassembling a generator yields surprising results

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield, python-internals

I know how to use generators but I don't know anything about their internals. I tried this:

```
In [4]: def f(): yield 1
In [6]: type(f())
Out[6]: generator
```

Now I disassemble it:

```
In [7]: dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 YIELD_VALUE         
              4 POP_TOP             
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Why does the opcodes suggest `return None` while `f` actually returns a generator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All functions return `None` at their end if there is no explicit return, generators are no exception. As of Python 3.3, generators can [return a final value](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) when ending, but in Python 2.7 a blank return is mandatory if you use `return` to end the function early.

This is a 'limitation' of how Python frames are implemented; you have to have a `RETURN_VALUE` opcode to exit the frame cleanly and unwind the stack, and that opcode requires an operand, always.

Calling the function still produces a generator, but the *byte code* isn't executed until you actually call the `.next()` method on the generator.